# Не удается вытащить значение из MySQL для использования в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Есть необходимость получать все данные, которые имеются о пользователе в базе данных для последующей их обработки/изменений.

Что имею:

```
  if (count($errors) == 0) { // Если пользователь ввел свои данные правильно, то продолжаем 
$password = md5($password); // дешифровка пароля 
$query = "SELECT username, password, email FROM trackowners WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"; // запрос данных
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  ///////////
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  header('location: index.php');
}else {
  array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
} }
```

Далее, пытаюсь использовать переменные "$_SESSION['username']" и аналогичную для электронной почты:

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> // Here are your profile settings.</p>

    <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
<?php endif ?>

  <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
  <p>Your e-mail<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong> //</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

И вот тут происходит следующее: переменная username отображается, а переменная email - нет. В чем может быть проблема, если они одинаково вызываются и обозначаются в скрипте?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а какое значение у $email ? откуда оно берётся?

Comment: По моему пониманию, я его запрашиваю в $query (через SELECT), но, вообще, я его обозначаю чуть выше:  `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']); // `

Comment: > я его запрашиваю в $query (через SELECT).. нет конечно, в вашем запросе нет этого,  у вас явно в $_POST['email'] пустота, там проверяйте. PS > $password = md5($password); // дешифровка пароля  - md5()  это не дешифровка, а шифрование(!)

Comment: Шифрование паролей алгоритмом `md5` было актуальным году в 2010-м.

Comment: Я не пытаюсь сейчас сделать современное шифрование, для меня это пока еще рано и сложно. Не понимаю, почему email пустой. Значение в датабазе точно есть..

Comment: Я не вижу, что вы где то запрашивали email. у вас во всем алгоритме используются только две переменные $username и $password. А потом вы в сессию присваиваете эту самую $email, которая ранее нигде не встречается. Если вы утверждаете, что берете ее из POST, то выходит, что у вас пользователь вводит одновременно имя, пароль и еще email ? не встречал таких авторизаций с вводом сразу трех полей ...